# change index number in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook to write some tutorials. However, I met a problem here. As shown in following picture, when I made changes to my colleague's notebook program, the index is not right. how to change those in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XllRd.png), in [2] to in [34], in [35]?[image]

Comment: You'll need to open the json notebook and edit the line like this: `"execution_count": 1` and change to `"execution_count": 34` and so on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click the menu `Cell` --> `Run all`. This will execute all cells and you will have ordered cell index numbers. If it does not start from cell index `1`,  first click `Kernel` --> `Restart` and confirm the re-start.

Comment: Any easier way without re-running everything?

Comment: Addressing the question "without rerunning".....By opening the executed `.ipynb` file saved from the notebook in your favorite text editor, you can technically edit the json code in the `.ipynb` so that the `"execution_count": 1,` reads whatever you want it to be for whatever cell. It is much safer to do a restart & run all cells so that the saved file actually represents what really happens. Plus, that insures you don't accidentally mess up the json formatting. But an `.ipynb` file is just json text that you could edit in a pinch if you are careful. Alexey's answer uses a script for that.

Answer (score 6):

This simple Python snippet would do it

```py
import json

with open(NOTEBOOK_FILE, 'rt') as f_in:
    doc = json.load(f_in)


cnt = 1

for cell in doc['cells']:
    if 'execution_count' not in cell:
        continue

    cell['execution_count'] = cnt

    for o in cell.get('outputs', []):
        if 'execution_count' in o:
            o['execution_count'] = cnt

    cnt = cnt + 1


with open(NOTEBOOK_FILE, 'wt') as f_out:
    json.dump(doc, f_out, indent=1)
```

(Make sure the notebook isn't running in Jupyter)

Comment: Extremely useful snippet! You saved me on a project where a requirement was to have a clean run-through on a notebook that I did not want to spend another 6 hours running  Thanks for the tip! It helps me better understand what notebooks really are under the hood :)

Comment: Alternatively... For others that maybe are less familiar with reworking json with a script, there is `nbformat` ([some background on `nbformat` available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72219343/8508004)) that can handle iterating over cells to do this type of task and has the attributes & concepts of notebooks, such as cell, `cell_type`,  &`execution_count`, baked in so that it makes it easier. [Version of Alexey's script using nbformat](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/facea67ed53a5a2065882ba25f6d54e7). `nbformat` is a handy tool if you want to edit notebooks programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem as follows:

*Jupyter Notebook Menubar* > `Kernel` > `Restart & Run All`