# how to programmatically add slides cell metadata in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, nbconvert

Jupyter notebooks has a way of visualizing cell metadata so that you are able to parametrize how will cells look like when you export the notebook into slides using `nbconvert`.

Example:
[image]

For instance, I would like to programmatically add that metadata into cells without using the GUI, so that I can automate slide creation, specially from google colaboratory as it doesn't support the *Edit Cell Metadata* tool.

I've come across this reference

https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/content/metadata.html#add-tags-using-python-code

which programmatically adds metadata to hide cell code. I would like to be able to do the same but **adding slideshow metadata**. For instance I am not sure what `{tags:values}` or syntax I should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nbformat](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#) to do this like the example you point to.

> "The nbformat package allows you to programmatically read and parse notebook files." - [SOURCE, Tony Hirst's description](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-wrap-markdown-cells/1529/2?u=fomightez)

nbformat comes as part as Jupyter so it runs wherever you have your notebooks running.

I use nbformat to do something similar to your goal [here](https://github.com/fomightez/imgs2RISEslides) (in a work-in-progress state). The most pertinent part is [here](https://github.com/fomightez/imgs2RISEslides/blob/07b0a85960129c5533503aa89c469ae7253908f4/imgs2RISEslides.ipy#L259) where I set the meta data for cells in the notebook to be a slide show. Here's the gist of that section:

```py
import nbformat as nbf
a = nbf.v4.new_notebook()
for p in image_fn_pairs:
    content_for_md_cell = slideshow_cell_stub_text.replace(
        "THE_IMAGE1_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT_GOES_HERE",p[0]).replace(
        "THE_IMAGE2_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT_GOES_HERE",p[1])
    a.cells.append(nbf.v4.new_markdown_cell(content_for_md_cell))
# fix the metadata for each cell to be for a slide
slide_show_meta = {"slideshow": {"slide_type": "slide"}}
# a.cells = [c["metadata"] = slide_show_meta for c in a.cells]
meta_fixed_cells = []
for c in a.cells:
    c["metadata"] = slide_show_meta
    meta_fixed_cells.append(c)
a.cells = meta_fixed_cells
```

In your case, it sounds like you already have the content in your notebook, and so in your case you'll want to read in the notebook, like this first:

```py
import nbformat as nbf
ntbk = nbf.read("old_notebook.ipynb", nbf.NO_CONVERT)
```

And then fix the metadata like my example. Something along these lines:

```py
new_ntbk = ntbk
# fix the metadata for each cell to be for a slide
slide_show_meta = {"slideshow": {"slide_type": "slide"}}
meta_fixed_cells = []
for c in ntbk.cells:
    c["metadata"] = slide_show_meta
    meta_fixed_cells.append(c)
new_ntbk.cells = meta_fixed_cells
nbf.write(new_ntbk, "notebook_with_slide_metadata.ipynb", version=nbf.NO_CONVERT)
```

---

You can try the automated, work-in-progress slide building process I set up and referred to above by going [there](https://github.com/fomightez/imgs2RISEslides) and clicking `launch binder`. I think if you just run things in the notebook that comes up it will guide you through making slides with some filled rectangles side-by-side on each slide as stand-in for images.

You'll also see I use a stub of a notebook in [the script](https://github.com/fomightez/imgs2RISEslides/blob/07b0a85960129c5533503aa89c469ae7253908f4/imgs2RISEslides.ipy#L135), that is based on [a notebook stub](https://github.com/fomightez/imgs2RISEslides/blob/master/RISEnb_stub.ipynb) to add in metadata for the entire notebook [here](https://github.com/fomightez/imgs2RISEslides/blob/07b0a85960129c5533503aa89c469ae7253908f4/imgs2RISEslides.ipy#L285) so that it will play the slideshow automatically when the notebook is opened, i.e., the `"livereveal": {"autolaunch": true, "scroll": true}` section.

---

---

nbconvert includes a preprocessor that will edit metadata, see [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/a8067447af4a90690b762f48ceb46d40207a344e/nbconvert/exporters/slides.py#L15) where it looks like it will add the metadata.

---

---

If you use JupyterLab as your slide development tool, you can install jupyterlab-deck which will add a 'deck' icon to the toolbar that allows you to toggle in and out of the slidedeck viewing. See [Usage here](https://github.com/deathbeds/jupyterlab-deck#usage). (In deck mode of sessions served via MyBinder, I see the toolbar if I move the mouse towards the top of screen. I assume this is because `shift+esc` doesn't work. Or the documentation just hasn't been updated.)